# Strong Parameters Nested Attributes, ActionController Unknown Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nested-attributes, strong-parameters, http-post

Trying to get nested attributes working with my POST requests.

The create and privates method in my controller looks like this:

```
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :ok }
    end

    Event.create!(event_params)
  end

  private

  def event_params
    #puts "**** #{params.to_yaml}"

    params.require(:event).permit(:name, parameters_attributes: [:topic_name])
  end
```

An instance of Event is created, but parameters doesn't. Also, I get an ActionController:UnknownFormat error.  The private method looks right according to the nest attributes docs I've looked at, but not following why Event creates but Parameter doesn't.

Heroku logs give this.

```
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"name"=>"Topic Views", "topic_name"=>"First Topic to Prepare Bloccit for API Testing", "created_at"=>"2014-04-15 00:22:38 UTC", "event"=>{"name"=>"Topic Views", "created_at"=>"2014-04-15 00:22:38 UTC", "topic_name"=>"First Topic to Prepare Bloccit for API Testing"}}
I, [2014-04-21T05:56:08.116439 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms
F, [2014-04-21T05:56:08.117418 #2] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

**UPDATE**

```
  def create
    @event = Event.create!(event_params)
    @event.parameters.create!(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { head :ok }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def event_params      
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, parameters_attributes: [:topic_name])
  end
```

Comment: It should be `parameter_attributes` i think so,not `parameters_attributes`

Comment: which model is it associated with?

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

> 1. You're not passing nested attributes
> 2. You're firing your `create!` method *after* the `respond_to` block

I'd firstly sort out your `create` method:

```
def create
    event = Event.new(event_params)
    event.save #-> did this for convention. You can use create! if you want!

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { head: ok }
        format.js
    end
end
```

Secondly, your form is not passing your nested attributes correctly:

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"Topic Views", "topic_name"=>"First Topic to Prepare Bloccit for API Testing", "created_at"=>"2014-04-15 00:22:38 UTC", "event"=>{"name"=>"Topic Views", "created_at"=>"2014-04-15 00:22:38 UTC", "topic_name"=>"First Topic to Prepare Bloccit for API Testing"}}
```

Inside the `events` params hash, you should have `paramaters_attributes:`, but you don't. This is basically caused by not building the associated ActiveRecord Object when you fire the `new` method. You'll need this:

```
#app/controllers/events_controller.rb
def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event.parameters.build
end

#app/views/events/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :parameters do |p| %>
        <%= p.text_field :attr %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

Because you're not using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you'll be better using the params hash as it stands:

```
def event_params      
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :topic_name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm not using forms.  The events are created when the POST requests hit the server, not via forms in the view

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The events are created when POST requests hit the server, not via forms in the view.  With your changes, minus the form_for..., events and parameters are being created, but the :topic_name attribute is returning nil instead of the right value.

Comment: The topic_name attr is returning nil? Can you update with your sent params etc

Comment: Please see the updated create method.  I receive the name and topic_name parameters via the POST request --- Parameters: {"name"=>"Topic Views", "topic_name"=>"First Topic to Prepare Bloccit for API Testing", "created_at"=>"2014-04-15 00:22:38 UTC", "event"=>{"name"=>"Topic Views", "created_at"=>"2014-04-15 00:22:38 UTC", "topic_name"=>"First Topic to Prepare Bloccit for API Testing"}}

Comment: Updated Answer for you

Comment: I'm using accepted_nested_attributes_for in my Event model. Please see the update